# Netbeans IDE 7.3.1 unable to create Java Web

Tags: java, netbeans-7

I am having a problem with my *newly* installed Netbeans and when I tried to create a Java Web by following their instructions: **Choose File > New Project. Under Categories, select Java Web. Under Projects, select Web Application. Click Next.**

But the problem is, Java Web isn't under the categories. Did I **NOT** install something correctly? I have JDK 1.6 and JDK 1.7 installed. So I have no idea what is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go to the Tools menu and select Plugins.
2. Click on the "Available Plugins" tab.
3. Check the box for "Java Web Applications".
4. Click the "Install" button.
5. Click through all dialogs until the plugin and its dependencies are installed.
6. Restart the IDE.

Comment: **EDIT:** Thank you. I didn't had this problem the first time I installed Netbeans on another computer, so I had no idea how to troubleshoot this problem. Thanks for that quick response that resolved it. Cheers mate!